# Using indexOf in Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

Working with Jade & Express here.

`'#{value.users}'` is an array.

`'#{user.username}'` is a string.

Trying to do `if '#{value.users}'.indexOf('#{user.username}')`

If true, then I display a bunch of stuff, otherwise, shouldn't be rendered.

Jade is ok with the syntax, but even when `#{value.users}'.indexOf('#{user.username}')` is falsy, the content within the if statement is being rendered.

For instance, if user.username = `bob`, and value.users = `['tim', 'billy']`, the `if` statement is passing, when it clearly shouldn't be.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check what `['tim', 'billy'].indexOf('bob')` yields: `-1`. Not a falsy value (`0`)

Answer (score 6):

Shouldn't it be `#{value.users.indexOf(user.username)}`?

Any js commands inside `#{}` is executed. You should be able to fit your entire expression inside a single `'#{}'`

By saying `if '#{value.users}'.indexOf('#{user.username}')` the `'#{value.users}'` is being serialised into a string and when using `.indexOf()` it's searching within the string, rather than original array.

If you are using it in an if statement, why not just execute the js directly?
eg.

```
- if ( value.users.indexOf(user.username) )
    p some jade
- else
    p alternate jade
```

https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#a8

Alternatively, you could use the underscore library.

http://underscorejs.org/#indexOf

If you want to use it inside Jade templates, be sure to require() it in your app or request locals.

Answer (score 5):

I am not familiar with Jade, but wouldn't you need to test against != -1 or == 1?

```
 str.indexOf('#{user.username}') ! = -1
```

or since you are testing against an array, something along the lines of.

```
 array.toString().indexOf('#{user.username}') != -1
```

UPDATE: With the advent of ES6, I updated a little below

```
 array.includes('#{user.username}') // returns true or false
 str.includes('#{user.username}') // returns true or false
```

Comment: `array.toString()` completely changes the meaning of the code.